# Can't access Gohma in OoT3D?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, zelda-ocarina-of-time

In the Inside of the Deku Tree dungeon, to access the boss, Gohma, you have to deflect bullets from enemies (I can't remember their name) in a certain order. Before, another enemy tells you said order. This order is **2-3-1** (for me at least).

The problem is, no matter how many times I deflect the bullets in that order, no matter how fast/slow I try, the enemies always reset (as in, they go back into the ground). Am I doing something wrong here or is my game bugged?

Comment: Which side are you considering to be 1 and 3? Are you doing it **middle, right, left**?

Comment: @Ben I'm doing __right, left, middle__.

Comment: In the original the positions of the deku's were 1 2 3. So my original order was correct. However on the newer versions this may have been changed up as I explained in my answer below.

Comment: Yeah, it actually was middle, left, right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the remastered versions this has been changed up.

> In the Master Quest re-releases no clue to their weakness is provided at any point prior to the encounter. The order is also changed from the original game which makes the battle more challenging since Link must guess the order in which he must defeat the brothers.

Taken from the [wiki](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Deku_Scrub_Brothers)